# How to change a background color in whole App?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to set up the background of the whole app (same default background for each view) in one place? For example in the **SceneDelegate**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom `ViewModifier`, throw in your color, and add it to your views. For instance, if you want all your views to be orange, do this:

```
struct BackgroundColorStyle: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {        
        return content
            .background(Color.orange)
    }
}
```

And usage is:

```
Text("Hello world!").modifier(BackgroundColorStyle())
```

Now, you can - and probably should - expand on this for light/dark mode. In this case, you can use the environment variable `ColorSchmem`:

```
struct BackgroundColorStyle: ViewModifier {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View { 
        if colorScheme == .light {
            return content
                .background(Color.darkGrey)
        } else {
            return content
                .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, every `View` using this modifier has their background color defined in one place. If you wish to define a border along with a background color, same thing.

Comment: While I really appreciate this answer the real question was about setting default background for each view in a hierarchy in JUST one place

Comment: @SzymonW, this is likely the best way to do this in SwiftUI. While you can set a background color for a status bar appearance along with having access to a `UIHostingController` - the latter seems to me to be risky for this - in `SceneDelegate`, I'll go with my stock question for things like this: *"How would you do this in UIKit?"* If you provide some code, maybe someone can give you a better SwiftUI answer.

Comment: Since I was unable to find a better solution I'll mark this answer as a proper one, thank you :)

Comment: @SzymonW, glad to help. Trust me, my background is OOP and not Reactive, and what Apple introduced is a serious paradigm change. Maybe - maybe - next year with "SwiftUI 2.0" they'll introduce things (my choices include replacements for UIImagePickerController & UIActivityViewController) but for now this is what we're stuck with. FYI? About using UIHostingViewController - I think it's risky *because* of how "raw" the current version of SwiftUI is. Someday - be it next year or in a few years -  I think this won't be there.

Comment: Use an assets catalog for dark/light colors and you can also drop @Environment and the if.

Answer (score 4):

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Text("Hello World!")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

ZStack and Rectangle(), Setting foregroundColor and edgesIgnoringSafeArea

[image: demo]

Comment: Good answer, but two issues. (1) As the OP commented on my answer, they are looking for something in `SceneDelegate`. More importantly, this only sets the background of a single view. Now it *does* nicely work for a single screen app (which is something I do) but if you have a "stacked" app that uses a `NavigationView` you'll need to do this in every full screen view. Still, I think it's a good answer for some apps.